# Exact matching w/ SSIS Fuzzy matching

Tags: sql-server, ssis, fuzzy-comparison, fuzzy

I'm using the Fuzzy Matching SSIS component and want to do a fuzzy match on new names (from input columns Name1) against known names (Alias from Lookup Columns).  Doing this alone works great (and is fast), but when I want to restrict the matching to only those records that have the same Country code as shown below, BTW both columns are char(3) is ISO codes, SSIS performance is so slow that it never completes.

[image]

I've attempted every variation of indexing available on the [Reference Table] tab and I believe I'm using the combination of Relationships correctly per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186488.aspx

Anyone run into a similar issue and figure out a workable solution?

Adding answer to question asked in comments here (better formatting);

SQL Server version : 2014 Ent

SSIS Version : not sure, but created w/ SQL Server data tool for VS 2013

Data Volume Source : 65K

Data Volume Data to Match : 105K (but SSIS pipeline gets stuck around 10k)

SQL Server indicates it's waiting for SSIS to pull more data in
Looking at task manager DTSdebug is using ~15% CPU and will do so indefinitely

The really odd thing is if I remove the country matching (which is set to exact) and use a larger source set (172K vs 65K) SSIS runs wonderfully.

Comment: what data volumes are in your source and destination? What does SQL Server indicate it is doing when the Fuzzy and Exact are running? Which version of SQL Server/SSIS are you using?

Comment: @billinkc - all good questions... I updated my original with answers since it's easier to format there.